CUDA convert GUFF to CUDA GUFF
Now I use llama.cpp with cuda.
And I load Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct-Q6_K.gguf from huggingface but it was not for gpu.
So I have to rebuild it for gpu. How can I do it?

In that case, it is possible that there is not enough VRAM, or that parameters such as n_gpu_layers, n_ctx are not set appropriately. For information on settings, please refer to the following. If you try using a very small GGUF, you should be able to tell whether the problem is with VRAM or not.
Also, even if you build with CUDA specified, there are many cases where CUDA is not actually enabled.

